# How can "HierarchyID" type work when "CLR" is disabled?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, configuration, sql-clr

The following statement `sp_configure 'clr enabled'` returns:

```
name        minimum maximum config_value    run_value
clr enabled 0       1       0               0
```

I assume this means there are no `CLR` objects; however if I execute the following statements I get these:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.assembly_files
```

[image]

```
SELECT * FROM sys.assembly_types
```

[image]

I have [read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx) that `The HierarchyID type is available to CLR clients as the SqlHierarchyId data type.`.

How can it be used without having `CLR` enabled and why do I need to enable it to create my own `CLR` objects?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`clr enabled` server configuration option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175193.aspx) only controls whether **user** assemblies can be run by the SQL Server instance.

The `hierarchyid`, `geometry` and `geography` types are **system** CLR types. These are contained in system assemblies, so are available regardless of the `clr enabled` setting.

Similarly, other system features that rely on CLR integration, like [`FORMAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) (SQL Server 2012 onward) are available even if `clr enabled` is off.

If you need to manipulate `hierarchyid` data in a custom CLR routine, you will need to enable user clr assemblies via this setting.

See also: [Hierarchical Data (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx)