# Does lightweight pooling disable built-in CLR facilities?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017, sql-clr, format

Running SQL Server in fibre mode ([lightweight pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/lightweight-pooling-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017)) disables the use of SQL CLR:

> Common language runtime (CLR) execution is not supported under lightweight pooling. Disable one of two options: "clr enabled" or "lightweight pooling". Features that rely upon CLR and that do not work properly in fiber mode include the hierarchy data type, replication, and Policy-Based Management.

On the other hand, [disabling SQL CLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/clr-enabled-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017) alone (without enabling lightweight pooling) does **not** disable the built-in CLR types like `geometry`, and `geography` (though `hierarchyid` is mentioned above), as shown in [How can "HierarchyID" type work when "CLR" is disabled?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/77608)

Now some new language features rely on the CLR, for example [the `FORMAT` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> FORMAT relies on the presence of the .NET Framework Common Language Runtime (CLR).

Does running SQL Server in fibre mode disable the `FORMAT` function and/or using the CLR types?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Yes.

When running in fibre mode, everything that needs the CLR is unavailable, including `AT TIME ZONE`.

For example, both:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), N'd', N'en-us');
```

and:

```
DECLARE @g geometry;
SELECT @g;
```

...return the (slightly misleading) error message:

> Msg 5846, Level 16, State 2, Line 13
> Common language runtime (CLR) execution is not supported under lightweight pooling.
> Disable one of two options: "clr enabled" or "lightweight pooling".

It is the lightweight pooling that is the problem, no setting of the `clr enabled` option will allow CLR execution of any kind under lightweight pooling.

Comment: That is definitely a poorly worded error message, at least in that context. It makes the false assumption that the CLR-based functionality being attempted is from a user created Assembly, and so you need to choose one xor the other. They should have simply said: "Disable lightweight pooling to use CLR-based functionality (or because you shouldn't be using it anyway)". Though to be fair, this error message was probably just meant for when someone tries to use `sp_configure` to set both `clr enabled` and `lightweight pooling` to 1 at the same time, in which case the message does make sense.